# Wildcard certificate for internal server

Tags: ssl-certificate

My company sells application servers to customers; 90% of thoses servers are offline  in dedicated network.
We currently have a self signed certificate generated automatically according to the ip of the server.

**Will it be possible to buy a wildcard certificate and use it on all the servers locally ?**

Let's say we buy a certificate for *.mydomain.com (mydomain.com will be a real domain that we own). The certificate is installed on the servers. And on the local network we have a dns (or a modified host file) that map the servers's ip to a subdomain .
Will it be ok ? We just need to avoid the big warning in the browsers saying that the certificate is invalid. No need for EV certification or all this fancy things.

I tried it with let's encrypt and a standard certificate (not wildcard) and a modifed host file and it seems fine, but will it be ok with the "big" CA like Globalsign, Thwathe, etc ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not control TLS clients trust, and you do not issue certificates from any private PKI they may have, you are left with the generally trusted certificate authorities. Does not matter who issues them as long as the clients are configured to trust their CA.

Major problem with "wildcard" certs is that it is trusted for everything in `*.example.com`. That cert you issued to `appserver.example.com` can be used for `evil.example.com` or impersonate other servers. If you trust the app server administrator with everything in that DNS zone, fine, but sounds like you use this TLD for all your clients. [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2) goes as far as to say wildcards should not be used for best practice TLS domain verification.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the internal DNS it should be ok, to avoid buying a certificate is that if the client computers on your client that needs to connect to this server are managed you can request your client to add your self-signed certificate and CA to the authorized and update their policies.

In case you are using let's encrypt it will be transparent for your client and the computers.